# NTP synchronisation in Ubuntu Core

Tags: time, ubuntu-core, ntp

How can I configure a proper NTP synchronization in Ubuntu Core (version 10).

I am running the following version:

`ubuntu-core         2016-05-24 10                 ubuntu`

I tried using:

`root@localhost:/home/ubuntu# sudo timedatectl
      Local time: Tue 2016-07-05 14:16:50 UTC
  Universal time: Tue 2016-07-05 14:16:50 UTC
        RTC time: Tue 2016-07-05 14:16:51
       Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
     NTP enabled: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a`

and I did enable NTP. I didn't synchronize, even after reboots. I believe this is due to the fact that no proper NTP servers are configured:

`root@localhost:/home/ubuntu# cat /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`
`[Time]`

`#NTP=
*#FallbackNTP=0.debian.pool.ntp.org 1.debian.pool.ntp.org 2.debian.pool.ntp.org 3.debian.pool.ntp.org`

and this file is read only for me. I am stuck here - any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Best to just install this [ntp server](https://uappexplorer.com/app/ntpserver.cargonza) snap:

```
sudo snap install ntpserver
```

Answer (score 0):

On recent version of Ubuntu Core, the file is no longer read-only and a space-separated list of servers can be inserted in the `NTP=` option.

If you want to automate fixing it:

```
sed 's/^#*NTP=.*$/NTP=ntp.domain.com ntp2.domain.com/' /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf > /tmp/ntp_conf \
&& cat /tmp/ntp_conf > /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf \
&& rm /tmp/ntp_conf && systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd.service
```

This uses a temporary file in `/tmp`, since the rest of the directory is read-only, which prevents `sed -i` from working.